# Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I just learnt how to use Arrays i wrote this program in Java on Netbeans. It compiled with no errors but gave me a blank output my `if` was true but when it jumped to the `else` the output was ok

THIS IS MY JAVA CLASS

```
public class VacationScale {

   public int[] vacationDays;
   public int yearsOfService;

   public void setVacationScale(){
       vacationDays = new int[7];
       vacationDays[0] = 10;
       vacationDays[1] = 15;
       vacationDays[2] = 15;
       vacationDays[3] = 15;
       vacationDays[4] = 20;
       vacationDays[5] = 20;
       vacationDays[6] = 25;       
   }

   public void displayVacationDays(){
       if (yearsOfService >= 0){
           System.out.println("Vacation days: " + vacationDays[yearsOfService]);
       }else {
           System.out.println("invalid number of years");
       }

   }

}
```

AND THIS IS MY MAIN CLASS (TESTING)

```
public class VacationScaleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VacationScale personOne;
        personOne = new VacationScale();

        personOne.yearsOfService = 2;
        personOne.displayVacationDays();
    }

}
```

BOTH IN THE SAME PROJECT

i tried debugging and got **Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code** at
`System.out.println("Vacation days: " + vacationDays[yearsOfService]);`

Comment: You never call `setVacationScale()` so members are default values (including a null array that you'll try to reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you still haven't set the array vacationDays[] at the point you make the call to displayVacationDays().

Do the following - add this line before the line where you have personOne.displayVacationDays(),

```
personOne.setVacationScale();
// Now make the call to display vacation days
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message in a completely different constellation.

I'm using java fx

I googled for it and found no similar cases. After some tests, I found out that when creating a new PropertyValueFactory I got this nerving error message.

The line of code that caused the problem was:

```
            TableColumn<Values, String> col = new TableColumn<>(val.getName());

            col.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Values,String>("Value")
            );
```

The class Values is a subclass and looks like this:

```
private class Values {
    private final SimpleStringProperty vall;
    public Values(String d) {
        this.vall = new SimpleStringProperty(d);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return vall.get();
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        vall.set(value);
    }
}
```

**Solution:**
After a lot of checking, I found out that my Values class must be PUBLIC and not private.

```
 public class Values {
...
}
```

I hope it can be useful for someone.